# Statsmodels OLS Linear Regression - Why do I have multiple regression parameters?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm performing a linear regression to fit y=x+c1+c2+c3+c4+...+cn (c1..cn are covariates).

Something odd is happening once I output the summary results, and I am not sure why this is the case:

```
    OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                   pgrs   R-squared:                       0.038
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.012
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.7565
Date:                Wed, 16 Aug 2017   Prob (F-statistic):              0.716
Time:                        11:12:02   Log-Likelihood:                -18.623
No. Observations:                 284   AIC:                             67.25
Df Residuals:                     269   BIC:                             122.0
Df Model:                          14                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
================================================================================
                   coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept        0.5331      0.272      1.957      0.051      -0.003       1.069
x[T.0]    -0.2568      0.327     -0.786      0.433      -0.900       0.387
x[T.1]    -0.0574      0.280     -0.205      0.837      -0.608       0.493
x[T.2]    -0.1556      0.277     -0.562      0.575      -0.701       0.390
x[T.3]     0.0182      0.273      0.067      0.947      -0.519       0.555
x[T.4]    -0.0114      0.271     -0.042      0.967      -0.545       0.523
x[T.5]     0.0067      0.272      0.025      0.980      -0.529       0.542
x[T.6]    -0.0321      0.269     -0.119      0.905      -0.562       0.498
x[T.7]     0.0262      0.271      0.097      0.923      -0.507       0.559
x[T.8]    -0.0542      0.270     -0.200      0.841      -0.586       0.478
x[T.9]    -0.0529      0.272     -0.195      0.846      -0.588       0.482
c1           0.0625      0.039      1.615      0.107      -0.014       0.139
c2           -0.0016      0.007     -0.219      0.827      -0.016       0.013
c3              0.2052      0.356      0.576      0.565      -0.496       0.906
c4              0.0986      0.397      0.249      0.804      -0.682       0.880
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.789   Durbin-Watson:                   1.865
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.248   Jarque-Bera (JB):                3.018
Skew:                          -0.000   Prob(JB):                        0.221
Kurtosis:                       3.505   Cond. No.                         525.
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Why do I have multiple x parameters? This only occurs for me when x is a particular feature in my dataset. Is there any way to resolve this, or is this some sort of intended behaviour, and what does it mean? Specifically, does the [T.0], ... [T.9] mean anything?

I'm using statsmodels to fit the above function.

```
    # Returns a string y ~ trait + c1 + ... + cn
    f = math_expr([trait] + covariates, y)
    lm = ols(formula=f, data=df).fit()
```

Comment: Would you please show us the statsmodels code you used to make this fit?

Comment: Sure, I included them now.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `math_expr`. If it's of any use, when I've been stuck trying to understand what model has been used I've resorted to running https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0/formulas.html to see the design matrices.

Comment: x is treated by patsy as a categorical variable. Maybe the values of x are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your data is not being interpreted as numerical, perhaps there is a placeholder for missing values in your data (e.g. a '?') that means the whole column will be assigned to a string type. You will need to convert your columns to numerical values, for example stick this snippet of code just after you import the dataframe:

```
df[column_name] = pd.to_numeric(df[column_name], errors='coerce')
```

The second argument will change change any error values (such as '?') to a numerical NaN.

Comment: This was the problem. Alternatively I corrected the pandas dataframe when reading in from the csv file to just ignore values that I set to "."